# Issue with linking graph and table to several inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and have an issue with the responsiveness of my graph & table.

My `merged` dataset consists of two variables (Length and Size), each of them having two distinct categories: `Length` can be either `Large` or `Small` or and `Size` can be either `Long` or `short`. There are also two different units: in `Volume` and in `Count`. I would like to create an app with a single graph, where either `Length` or `Size` would be displayed in either `Volume` or `Count`.

When I simplify this task by using only part of the `merged` dataset, i.e. either the `data1` or `data2` dataset below, everything works well as I only have one `selectInput()` (to choose the `Category`).

Here is a working dummy code in which only `data1` is used:

```
data1 <- data.frame(variable = rep("Size", 24), category = rep(c("Large","Small"), each = 12), unit = rep(c("Volume", "Count"), each = 6), date = rep(c("Jan 2000", "Feb 2000", "Mar 2000", "Apr 2000", "May 2000", "Jun 2000"), times = 2), quantity = c(0.9,2,3.1,3.7,4.7,5.9,106.6,207.3,329,450.6,513.3,610,6.5,9.2,10,10.8,10.7,13.6,802.6,765.3,996,1076.6,1151.3,1196))
data1$date <- as.yearmon(paste(data1$date),"%b %Y")
data2 <- data.frame(variable = rep("Length", 24), category = rep(c("Long","Short"), each = 12), unit = rep(c("Volume", "Count"), each = 6), date = rep(c("Jan 2000", "Feb 2000", "Mar 2000", "Apr 2000", "May 2000", "Jun 2000"), times = 2), quantity = c(1.8,6.8,4.3,1.6,8.4,11.8,362.4,290.2,148,811,1026.6,2074,9.1,4.1,18,21.6,36.3,19,361.1,1377.5,1992,3660.4,1611.8,538.2))
data1$date <- as.yearmon(paste(data1$date),"%b %Y")
merged <- rbind(data1, data2)

# Define UI for application that draws time-series
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Dummy shiny"),

  # Create filters 
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("unit", label = h4("Display the dummy data in:"), 
                       unique(as.character(data1$unit)))
    ),
    column(4,
           sliderInput("date", label = h4("Select time range:"),
                       2000, 2000.5, value = c(2000, 2000.5), step = 0.1)
    )
  ),
  # Create a new row for the graph or the table (one in each tab)
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Graphical view", plotOutput("distPlot")),
    tabPanel("Data", dataTableOutput("distTable")))
)

# Define server logic required to draw the wanted time-series
server <- function(input, output) {
  dataInput <- reactive({
    data1[data1$unit==input$unit,]
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(dataInput(), aes(x = date, y = quantity, fill = category)) +
      geom_area(position = "stack") +
      xlab("") + ylab("") +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = input$date, expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
  })
  output$distTable <- renderDataTable({
    dataInput()
  },
  extensions = "Buttons",
  options = list(
    scrollY = "300px", pageLength = 10, scrollX = TRUE, dom = "Bftsp",
    buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel"))
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When trying to use the `merged` dataset instead of the `data1` dataset, I need to add another `selectInput()` (to choose the `Variable`) but I get an error when running the code.

In the code above, I simply added that bit in `fluidRow()` :

```
column(4,
           selectInput("var", label = h4("Choose variable to display:"), 
                       unique(as.character(merged$variable)))
    )
```

and replaced the `dataInput` bit by:

```
reactive({
    merged[merged$unit==input$unit | merged$variable==input$var,]
  })
```

It says "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". Do you have any idea why and how to solve this?

I also have two additional questions, which are much less annoying:

1. Is there a way to ensure that the table also responds to the time range?
2. Is there a way to keep dates as "%b %Y" instead of fractions in the table?

Thank you SO much for your help.

Comment: Place `browser()` just prior to `merged[...` but and rerun the app. See what the result looks like.

Comment: It just highlights `browser()` in yellow, and a continue & a stop buttons have appeared...
In the console, it says:
`Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  178: plyr::id
  177: add_group
  176: f
  175: l$compute_aesthetics
  174: f
  173: by_layer
  172: ggplot_build.ggplot
  170: print.ggplot
  162: func
  160: f
  159: Reduce
  150: do
  149: hybrid_chain
  121: drawPlot
  107: <reactive:plotObj>
   91: drawReactive
   78: origRenderFunc
   77: output$distPlot
    1: runApp` 

Is that helpful in some way or did I misunderstood what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after a sleepless night I've actually found a solution, mostly thanks to @deanattali 's amazing tutorial available at: https://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/.

The issue had to do with the way I previously subset my data. Here is the full working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data.frame(variable = rep("Size", 24), category = rep(c("Large","Small"), each = 12), unit = rep(c("Volume", "Count"), each = 6), date = rep(c("Jan 2000", "Feb 2000", "Mar 2000", "Apr 2000", "May 2000", "Jun 2000"), times = 2), quantity = c(0.9,2,3.1,3.7,4.7,5.9,106.6,207.3,329,450.6,513.3,610,6.5,9.2,10,10.8,10.7,13.6,802.6,765.3,996,1076.6,1151.3,1196))
data2 <- data.frame(variable = rep("Length", 24), category = rep(c("Long","Short"), each = 12), unit = rep(c("Volume", "Count"), each = 6), date = rep(c("Jan 2000", "Feb 2000", "Mar 2000", "Apr 2000", "May 2000", "Jun 2000"), times = 2), quantity = c(1.8,6.8,4.3,1.6,8.4,11.8,362.4,290.2,148,811,1026.6,2074,9.1,4.1,18,21.6,36.3,19,361.1,1377.5,1992,3660.4,1611.8,538.2))
merged <- rbind(data1, data2)
merged$date <- as.yearmon(paste(merged$date),"%b %Y")

# Define UI for application that draws time-series
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Dummy shiny"),

  # Create filters 
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("variableInput", label = h4("Display the dummy data in:"), 
                       unique(merged$variable))),
    column(4,
           selectInput("unitInput", label = h4("Display the dummy data in:"), 
                       unique(merged$unit))),
    column(4,
           sliderInput("dateInput", label = h4("Select time range:"),
                       2000, 2000.5, value = c(2000, 2000.5), step = 0.1)
    )
  ),
  # Create a new row for the graph or the table (one in each tab)
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Graphical view", plotOutput("distPlot")),
    tabPanel("Data", dataTableOutput("distTable")))
)

# Define server logic required to draw the wanted time-series
server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered <- reactive({
    merged %>%
      filter(variable == input$variableInput,
             unit == input$unitInput,
             date >= input$dateInput[1],
             date <= input$dateInput[2]
    )%>%
    select(-c(1,3))
})
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = date, y = quantity, fill = category)) +
      geom_area(position = "stack") +
      xlab("") + ylab("") +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = input$date, expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
  })
  output$distTable <- renderDataTable({
    filtered()
  },
  extensions = "Buttons",
  options = list(
    scrollY = "300px", pageLength = 10, scrollX = TRUE, dom = "Bftsp",
    buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel"))
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```